# Scape using Beautiful Soup failed on hidden items

Tags: web-scraping, web

Can anyone teach me how to scrape the "model #" off this this HomeDepot webpage? I am able to get the price and name but not the model#. Thanks a lot.

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib

url = "https://www.homedepot.ca/en/home/categories/tools/power-tools/power-tool-combo-kits/f/makita/uc1-5yu"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                         'Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept-Language': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,'
                              'image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
content = response.text
# print(content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
price = soup.find_all("div", role="text", class_="acl-product-card__price-dollars")
title = soup.find_all("h2", class_="acl-product-card__title acl-line-limit--3")
# model = soup.find_all("span _ngcontent-hdca-c173=""", class_="acl-product-card__com--modal ng-star-inserted")
# print(model)

for i in range(len(title)):
    print(int(price[i].getText().replace("And", "").replace("$", "").replace(",", "")))
    # print(model[i].getText().split()[2])
    print(title[i].getText())
```